# Can I create a database link on a read-only user?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a database A where I have `CREATE DATABASE LINK` privilege and a database B where I can connect as a read-only user (I don't have the privilege here). I just want to do `SELECT` queries.

I would like to know if it's possible to create a database link on this user.

I did many researches about my problem, but nothing works.

I also tried `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY` but it did nothing.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE LINK dblink_name
CONNECT TO user_with_read_only
IDENTIFIED BY password
USING('(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<host>)(PORT=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<service_name>)))
```

I got those errors:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-16000: database open for read-only access
```

Comment: According to [this document from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/ds_admin.htm#i1007820) you will need the `create session` privilege on the remote database in order to create the link.

Comment: It seems to be complaining that you have a read-only local database; not that the remote database user is read-only (however you are defining that - presumably only select privs on objects, no insert/update/delete/execute)?

Comment: @Michael I have `create session` privilege on the user of the remote database, but it doesn't work.
@AlexPoole I can only do `select` with the remote database user.